# RunAs Fails on Win 10 with MasterSeeker Without Error

Tags: windows, runas, masterseeker

I want to execute MasterSeeker with RunAs.

Run normally, MasterSeeker forces user to enter admin password, without choosing "Run as administrator".

If i right-click, i can "Run as administrator" no problem.

But the following command doesn't run the program.

```
runas /user:DESKTOP-9MOOUDP\BOOM "C:\Program Files\MasterSeeker1.5.1\MasterSeeker.exe"

Enter the password for DESKTOP-9MOOUDP\BOOM:

Attempting to start C:\Program Files\MasterSeeker1.5.1\MasterSeeker.exe as user "DESKTOP-9MOOUDP\BOOM" ...
```

Comment: Your not elevating the permissions of the process with your command, your just running the process, with a user with Administrative privileges. Processes by default run at the lowest permissions possible.

Comment: Unclear. RunAs admin doesn't run apps with admin privileges?

Comment: You’re not using tuna Administrator. You’re running it as a specific user who is an Administrator. Which goes back to the first rule. A process saloons at the lowest permission possible unless elevated which would require a UAC prompt. The two methods that work do exactly that

Comment: @Ramhound tuna? saloons?

Comment: What’s confusing? Just because you ran the process as a user who is an Administrator doesn’t mean the process permissions were elevated. My comment clearly contains multiple typos but I don’t recall what the original word was.

Comment: @Ramhound Unclear how running a process as a particular user wouldn't run with that user's permissions. Unclear why that seems non-confusing to you.

Comment: My own ignorance of knowing how Windows works I suppose. You have to “run as Administrator” to elevate the permissions of a process on Windows. Running it as a specific user isn’t enough.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/mrkrch/Elevation-PowerToys) is Elevation the duplicate talks about